# Replicate Summation Operator in MATLAB

Tags: loops, matlab, iteration, symbolic-math, function-handle

I'm trying to model the following time dependent function in MATLAB:

[image]

where gamma,beta, and delta are constants.
I'm not sure what the best way to approach the summation is. I could make u(t) and y(t) function handles, but symsum can only be used for symbolics. Is my only option to use a for loop to manually add up y(t-i) and u(t-m)? What I have done so far to generate y(t) is shown below:

```
N = 100;
y_out = zeros(N,1);
u = zeros(N,1);

for t = 1:1:N
u(t) = cos(beta*t);
end

y_out(1) = NARMA(beta,delta,gamma,true);
for t=2:N
    y_out(t) = NARMA(beta,delta,gamma);
end


function y_out = NARMA(beta,delta,gamma,first_call)
    % Set first_call to true only the first time you call the function
    persistent y
    if nargin>3 && first_call
        y = 0;
    end

    for i=1:1:m
    y = y + gamma*u + delta;
    end

    y_out = y;

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that doesn't require loop (not tested):

```
t = 1:N;
u = @(t) cos(beta * t);
y = cumsum(gamma * u(t - m) .* u(t) + delta);
y(m+1:end) = y(m+1:end) - y(1:end-m);
```

**EDIT:**

It turned out that the above solution is wrong. I think this is correct:

```
u = @(t) cos(beta*t);
y = zeros(N+m, 1);
for t = 1:N
    y(t+m) = sum(y(t:t+m-1)) + gamma * u(t-m) * u(t) + delta;
end
y = y (m+1:end);
```

**EDIT2:**

With further simplifications the summation can be reduced to a simple for loop:

```
u = @(t) cos(beta*t);
y = zeros(N+m, 1);
e = gamma * u((1:N)-m) .* u(1:N) + delta;
de = diff(e);
y(1+m) = e(1);
for t = 2:N
    y(t+m) = 2 * y(t+m-1) - y(t-1) + de(t-1);
end
y = y (m+1:end);
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach.  What would change if I added y(t-1) to the original equation I gave for y(t) outside of the summation? (In other words if the equation became: y(t) = y(t-1) + summation(gamma*u(t-m)*u(t)+delta)? Would you have to initialize the size of y to a N by 1 matrix? Would t have to change to t=2:N since Matlab starts at index 1 not 0? @rahnema1

Comment: In this cast the result should be: `y = cumsum(gamma * u(t - m) .* u(t) + delta);`.  No need to initialize `y`. Here the result is a `1` by `N` matrix. If you need a `N` by `1` matrix just transpose the result. Possibly you need to change `t` to `t=0:N-1` because time starts from 0.

Comment: I did not communicate my follow up question very well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226144/replicate-a-time-dependent-function-in-matlab