# Replicate a Time Dependent Function in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, symbolic-math, function-handle

I'm trying to replicate the following function in MATLAB:
[image]

where beta, gamma, and delta are constants.

What I have so far is below. The summation should only be applied to y(t-i) as indicated by the square brackets in:

```
beta = 0.3;
gamma = 0.5;
delta = 0.2;
m = 10;
N = 100;

y_out = NARMA(beta,delta,gamma,m,N);

function y_out = NARMA(beta,delta,gamma,m,N)
t = 2:N;
y = zeros (N,1);
u = @(t) cos(beta * t);
y = y(t-1) + cumsum(gamma * u(t - m) .* u(t) + delta);
y(m+1:end) = y(m+1:end) - y(1:end-m);
y_out = y;
end
```

After running this code y_out is a 99 by 99 double instead of a 99 by 1 double as it should be. How do I make y_out, aka my function output y(t), a 99 by 1 matrix output? Is there a better way to go about this?

An update: My new attempt is shown below. The summation should only be applied to y(t-i) as indicated by the square brackets in:[image]

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

beta = 0.3;
delta = 0.8;
gamma = 0.4;
m = 10

NARMA = @(y_in,t) [y_in + delta + gamma*cos(beta*(t- 
m))*cos(beta*t)+cumsum(y_in(m+1:end) - y_in(1:end-m)),t];

N = 100;
y_out = zeros(N,1);

y_out(1) = NARMA(0,0);
for t=2:N
    y_out(t) = NARMA(y_out(t-1),t-1);
end
```

My result for y_out is a 100 by 1 matrix with values of 1,2,3,... This is not what I should be getting. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: If a previous answer to a previous question doesn’t do the right thing, please don’t accept the answer and then post a new question essentially asking the same thing. You could instead continue your conversation over there with the person that answered your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77220498/7328782

Comment: Hi Cris. Sorry! I was trying to break up my question to understand it better conceptually. I will use the same thread in the future! @CrisLuengo

Comment: Shouldn't it be `y(t) = y(t-1) + gamma * u(t-m) * u(t) + delta + summation (y(t-i));`? The terms that don't depend on `i` should be placed before the summation.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I should have put brackets around the summation to indicate this. @rahnema1

Comment: How to you represent ''summation(y(t-i))? Do you still use cumsum? If so, don't you need to define i with a loop from i = 1 to m? Or is this what the line y(m+1:end) = y(m+1:end) - y(1:end-m) does? @rahnema1

Comment: When I look at this code, all I can think of is that `cumsum` and whatnot is too complicated.  It might speed up computation a bit, but if it prevents you from getting the right result, if you don't understand how the equation translates to `cumsum`, then don't use it. Just translate the equation using plain old loops and keep the syntax as simple as possible. If it then turns out too slow, you can try finding clever tricks to speed it up, but it's no good starting with the clever tricks.

Comment: Also, don't use `clear all`. `clear` by itself clears all the variables from the workspace, and that is all you need. When you add the `all` you also clear function definitions from memory, which means MATLAB must load them in again. It is just slowing down your script for no benefit.

Comment: It turned out that the `cumsum` solution is wrong. You need to use for loop. I updated my answer to your previous question. It is more compact than the current answer to this question but I recommend to follow suggestions that provided by  @CrisLuengo .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start simple. Type in each computation you see. Use loops, don't worry about efficiency. `cumsum` and the like can come later if your first attempt is not fast enough.

When I translate the equation into code in this way, I get this:

```matlab
beta = 0.3;
delta = 0.8;
gamma = 0.4;
m = 10;
N = 100;

y = zeros(N,1);
% y(0)=0, and also y(-1)=0 etc.
t = 1;
y(t) = gamma * cos(beta * (t-m)) * cos(beta * t) + delta;
for t = 2:N
    v = y(t-1);
    for i = 1:m
        if t-i > 0  % else we add 0
            v = v + y(t-i);
        end
    end
    v = v + gamma * cos(beta * (t-m)) * cos(beta * t) + delta;
    y(t) = v;
end
```

That's it. A loop to compute each `t`, and a loop for the summation. Yes, we can replace that inner loop with a call to `sum`. Yes, we can remove that `if` by properly setting the loop limits. Do we need to? No, not in the first version of the code. Keep it simple. If this is fast enough, then you're done. If it's not, then you have a version of the code to compare results against when you're trying to make it more efficient.

Comment: Cris, you bring up many valid points. Good coding practice should start with the basics (loops in this case) and then be modified later with memory saving methods (i.e. cumsum in this case). I didn't know that clear all gets rid of function memory! Good to know moving forward. @CrisLuengo

Comment: Cris, if you decided to take this one step even further by multiplying the summation term in square brackets (ie. [summation(y(t-i)]) by y(t-1), would you simply change line 18 to: v = v*y(t-1) + gamma * cos(beta * (t-m)) * cos(beta * t) + delta; ? @CrisLuengo

Comment: @JonathanFrutschy I guess you could initialize `v` before the summation to 1, then multiply it by `y(t-1)` after the sum. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Ok. Is there any reason why you choose to initialize v to 1 instead of y(1)? To be clear, the new equation I am proposing is:  https://ibb.co/L1HQKJJ The new term I am adding is in red. @CrisLuengo

Comment: @JonathanFrutschy Think about what happens in the code. First you set `v` equal to the first term. Then you iteratively add the terms within the summation. `v` is now equal to the first two terms. If you multiply `v` by `y(t-1)` then you're multiplying both the first and the second term by this quantity, not only the second term. Because the first term is equal to `y(t-1)`, you can divide it out, leaving the equation as `(1+sum(...))*y(t-1)`. So that is what we're doing: initialize `v` to 1, which is the first term, then in the loop add the sum term, then multiply these first two terms.

Comment: I see. Whenever you divide a term by itself, you are indirectly assuming that the term does not equal zero. Otherwise you could have a non-zero quantity divided by zero, resulting in infinity. Therefore, we set v equal to 1 to avoid infinity in this case. @CrisLuengo.

Comment: @JonathanFrutschy But the translation of "x+ax = (1+a)x" is also valid if x=0. Even though you "divide out" x, you don't really divide by x. You just change the order of the two multiplications and the addition in a way that doesn't affect the result.